# kubelet.exe on Windows Server Core (1709): unable to read physical memory

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet, windows-container

I've built `kubelet`, `kube-proxy` off `master` branch of `kubernetes` repository and when running `kubelet.exe` without any parameters I'm getting the following error:

`error: failed to run Kubelet: unable to read physical memory`

I'm building off`master` as none one of the `unstable` branches included the fix described (and fixed) [here 55031](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/55031), which I was hitting on `1.9.0-alpha.3`.

Comment: This seems like a permission issue to me, is this something you have already verified?

Comment: Not really, but not sure what it could be, I'm running it in an admin console. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

After looking into it for the last week or so, it seems VMware (Fusion in my case) doesn't correctly populate the SMBIOS data related to installed memory (which is used by `GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory` that will show the above error).

I was able to confirm that it's working fine on Hyper-V hosts. Will attempt a fix to the issue.

Comment: This has been fixed in [PR #57124](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/57124). Probably in version 1.10.0